# SSL for static websites in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, custom-domain

I have purchased domain with godaddy. I am hosting the static website in Google cloud. I am not able to configure SSL for custom domain in google cloud. I am using storage in google cloud for this. Please help with steps. Thanks

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https. You'll have to set up a load balancer, use a third-party Content Delivery Network with Cloud Storage, or serve your static website content from Firebase Hosting instead of Cloud Storage.

Comment: @LundinCast - You should post your comment (expanded a bit) as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use SSL certificates in GCP you need to have a Load Balancer created.
This [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing) explains it from the other point of view, how to add a Cloud Storage bucket when you already have a Load Balancer created, but the idea is the same.

Steps to take:

1. Create a HTTPs Load Balancer in Google Cloud Platform
2. Configure Backend to point to your Cloud Storage bucket
3. Configure Frontend to use your SSL certificate

It is a best practice to separate a dynamic part of the website (by using a backend to point to an instance group - that will go to GCE instance) and a static part (choosing a backend to be Cloud Storage). This way you are insuring the [speed and availability of the website](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#choosing_an_option).

You should also consider a [CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview) to cache a load balanced content close to your users.

[image]